# TextField within sheet not receiving focus

Tags: macos, swiftui

I have a TextField within a Sheet for a macOS app but the TextField doesn't receive any sort of focus when the sheet is presented. It's almost as if theres some sort of override on the focus state.

Interestingly, it works just as expected if I put it outside of the sheet. If this is a bug, then please suggest other workarounds.

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74831978/swiftui-macos-textfield-within-alert-not-receiving-focus/74833604#74833604) similar issue and wondering if this is a widespread bug for any presentable item whether that's sheet or alert.

Here's the code to try, just paste in a new Playground

#### Not working

```swift
import SwiftUI
import PlaygroundSupport

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var text = ""
    @FocusState private var focus: Bool
    @State private var showSheet = false
    
    var body: some View {
        Button(action : { showSheet = true }) {
            Label("Add", systemImage: "plus")
        }
        .frame(width: 150, height: 50)
        .sheet(isPresented: $showSheet) {
            LabeledContent {
                TextField("Enter Text", text: $text, onCommit: { focus = false })
                    .focused($focus) // ignores this
            } label: {
                Text("Field")
            }
            .padding()
            .defaultFocus($focus, false) // ignores this too
        }
    }
}

PlaygroundPage.current.setLiveView(ContentView())
```

#### Working

```swift
import SwiftUI
import PlaygroundSupport

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var text = ""
    @FocusState private var focus: Bool

    var body: some View {
        LabeledContent {
            TextField("Enter Text", text: $text, onCommit: { focus = false })
                .focused($focus)
        } label: {
            Text("Field")
        }
        .padding()
        .defaultFocus($focus, false)
    }
}

PlaygroundPage.current.setLiveView(ContentView())
```

*Tested on Xcode 15.0.1, macOS 14.1.1*

Comment: I'm using the same macOS versions as you but Xcode 15.0, and I cannot reproduce in an actual project (not a playground).

Comment: I was gonna add this note but this initially happened in a project and so I tried in a new project and new playground to see if the same result and focus was still not working for me.

Comment: Any suggestions?